# Output is sometimes right and false

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a java code to write a text file, and I'm printing the output to see if all conditions a correct, there are some cases the output is correct and some incorrect for the same condition. 
The cases are:

```
bpup >= 14  => out1 = 0  out 2 = 0

bpdown >= 9 => out1 = 0 out 2 = 1

bpup > 14 and bpdown > 9 => out1 = 1 out2 = 0 

bpup > 14 and bpdown > 9 and pulse <60 => out1 = 1 out2 = 1
```

Here's my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package pfetext;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class PFEtext {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    static int i = 10;
    static int out1;
    static int out2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
    int bpup;
    int bpdown;
    int pulse;
    int O2;    
         FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pfe.txt"); 
         BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(fw); 
         do {
         Random p = new Random();
         bpup = p.nextInt(23 - 3) + 3 ;
         bpdown = p.nextInt(17 - 4) + 4 ;
         pulse = p.nextInt(150 - 30) + 30 ;
         O2 = p.nextInt(100 - 40) + 40;

         //Epistaxis
         if(bpup >= 14){
         out1 = 0;
         out2 = 0;
         System.out.println("========== CASE EPISTACSIS ==========");
         System.out.println("BPUP " + bpup + " " + "BPDOWN " + bpdown + " " + "PULSE " + pulse + " " + "OUT1 " + out1 + " " + "OUT2 " + out2);
//         bw.write(bpup + "," + bpdown + "," + pulse + "," + O2 + "," + out1 + "," + out2);
//         bw.newLine();
         }

         //Blackout
         if(bpdown >= 9){
         out1 = 0;
         out2 = 1;
         System.out.println("========== CASE BLACKOUT ==========");
         System.out.println("BPUP " + bpup + " " + "BPDOWN " + bpdown + " " + "PULSE " + pulse + " " + "OUT1 " + out1 + " " + "OUT2 " + out2);
//         bw.write(bpup + "," + bpdown + "," + pulse + "," + O2 + "," + out1 + "," + out2);
//         bw.newLine();
         }

         //Epistaxis and Blackout
         if(bpup >= 14 && bpdown > 9){
         out1 = 1;
         out2 = 0;
         System.out.println("========== CASE EPISTACSIS & BLACKOUT ==========");
         System.out.println("BPUP " + bpup + " " + "BPDOWN " + bpdown + " " + "PULSE " + pulse + " " + "OUT1 " + out1 + " " + "OUT2 " + out2);
//         bw.write(bpup + "," + bpdown + "," + pulse + "," + O2 + "," + out1 + "," + out2);
//         bw.newLine();
         }

         //Numbness
         if(bpup >= 15 && bpdown >= 9 && pulse <= 60){
         out1 = 1;
         out2 = 1;
         System.out.println("========== NUMBNESS ==========");
         System.out.println("BPUP " + bpup + " " + "BPDOWN " + bpdown + " " + "PULSE " + pulse + " " + "OUT1 " + out1 + " " + "OUT2 " + out2);
//         bw.write(bpup + "," + bpdown + "," + pulse + "," + O2 + "," + out1 + "," + out2);
//         bw.newLine();
         } 
         i--;
         }while(i>0);


         bw.write(bpup + "," + bpdown + "," + pulse + "," + O2 + "," + out1 + "," + out2);
         bw.newLine();

         bw.close();      
    }

}
```

This is the output:

```
========== CASE BLACKOUT ==========
// correct
BPUP 9 BPDOWN 12 PULSE 106 OUT1 0 OUT2 1

========== CASE BLACKOUT ==========
// correct
BPUP 8 BPDOWN 11 PULSE 145 OUT1 0 OUT2 1

========== CASE BLACKOUT ==========
//correct
BPUP 7 BPDOWN 15 PULSE 103 OUT1 0 OUT2 1

========== CASE BLACKOUT ==========
// incorrect should be epistaxis and blackout
BPUP 13 BPDOWN 12 PULSE 145 OUT1 0 OUT2 1

========== CASE EPISTACSIS ==========
//correct
BPUP 18 BPDOWN 7 PULSE 125 OUT1 0 OUT2 0

========== CASE EPISTACSIS ==========
// incorrect should be epistaxis and blackout
BPUP 18 BPDOWN 11 PULSE 109 OUT1 0 OUT2 0

========== CASE BLACKOUT ==========
// incorrect should be epistaxis and blackout
BPUP 18 BPDOWN 11 PULSE 109 OUT1 0 OUT2 1

========== CASE EPISTACSIS & BLACKOUT ==========
// correct
BPUP 18 BPDOWN 11 PULSE 109 OUT1 1 OUT2 0

========== CASE BLACKOUT ==========
// correct
BPUP 3 BPDOWN 9 PULSE 107 OUT1 0 OUT2 1

========== CASE BLACKOUT ==========
//correct
BPUP 10 BPDOWN 10 PULSE 114 OUT1 0 OUT2 1
```

Comment: which case you are getting wrong answer? Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Do you realize that your 4 conditions are not mutual exclusive? This means that for the same input, more than one condition can be true. In order to avoid that, consider using if ... else if ... else if ...

Comment: Thanks Eran, I made a dumb mistake, I fixed the code and got the desired  results

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you, there is something wrong with the inequalities:

```
  //Epistaxis and Blackout
   if (bpup >= 14 && bpdown > 9) {
```

is true also for bpup = 14, while you say it must be true only for bpup > 14.

Furthermore:

```
//Numbness
   if (bpup >= 15 && bpdown >= 9 && pulse <= 60) {
```

is true for pulse = 60, while you say it must be true only for pulse < 60 and
is true for bpdown = 9, while you say it must be true only for bpdown > 9